# Error: "The Id field is required." while registering new user in database with AspNet.Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

Welcome,

I get the validation error mentioned in topic while creating (registering) new user in my Asp.Net mvc application where I used Asp.Net Identity with my custom ApplicationUser class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity>
    GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {      
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);   
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual string EmailConfirmedChar { get; set; }

    public virtual string PhoneNumberConfirmedChar { get; set; }

    public virtual string TwoFactorEnabledChar { get; set; }

    public virtual string LockoutEnabledChar { get; set; }
}
```

where my `TKey` is string, so I expect the `Id` to be `Guid` as it is by default.

Of course I implemented my custom UserStore, UserManager etc, in general I inspired by the blog post [Customizing the ASP.NET Identity Data Model with the Entity Framework Fluent API](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/Customizing-the-ASPNET-Identity-Data-Model-with-the-Entity-Framework-Fluent-API--Part-1)

What do I do wrong ? 
Generaly the same validation error appears  while downloaded the sample attached in this blog post.

Relevant or nor, I use Firebird database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`IdentityUser` class automatically generates GUID when you make a new instance of it. **Not** `IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TRole, TClaim>` class. 
However you could easily overcome this problem by generating new GUID in your `ApplicationUser` class constructor:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: Thank you , yes, assigning value in constructor of ApplicationUser class solved the issue, I Was not aware, that non generic class of User base class should generate new Id.