# Adding columns to AspNetUserClaims in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 2.2.1` in my solution. I need to integrate this with another system that should automatically add claims.

In order to keep track of which claims are manually added and which are created by an external system, I would like another column on my `AspNetUserClaims` table:

```
ExternalSystem varchar(64) null
```

How do I do this using EF Migrations (or without if nescessary), seeing as I don't actually have the claims class in my solution?

Comment: Are you using EF Core here?

Comment: Derive your own subclass with the additional property and when wiring up Identity use that instead.

Comment: @ChrisPickford: Subclass I get, but can you add a hint as to where to 'wire it up'? Do I need to subclass one of the managers?
DavidG: Not, full .NET

Comment: @TroelsLarsen - I'm afraid that if you want to diverge from the standard implementation it becomes quite a pain to implement. You'll need to create implementations of a lot of the Identity API. This article may help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity

Comment: @ChrisPickford: I already added a few fields to the user, but I'll see if I can find the appropriate place to extend the Claims as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create our own custom app user claim class which is derived from IdentityUserClaim class and add custom fields.

```
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim
{
    public ApplicationUserClaim() { }

    public ApplicationUserClaim(string userId, string claimType,
        string claimValue, string externalSystem)
    {
        UserId = userId;
        ClaimType = claimType;
        ClaimValue = claimValue;
        ExternalSystem = externalSystem;
    }

    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string ExternalSystem { get; set; }
}
```

After that, you need to configure ApplicationDbContext and ApplicationUser classes like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string,
        IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    // ...
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    // ...
}
```

Additionally, you have to create custom UserStore class like:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string,
        IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

And then you can use ApplicationUserManager like:

```
var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext();
var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(ctx));
```

Comment: Ah. Easier than I had thought. I will check this out as soon as I have time and accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not out of the woods yet. Changes also appear to be necessary in ApplicationUserManager, where the UserStore needs some extra generics arguments as well.

Comment: I forgot about usermanager and userstore. My answer has been updated. Thanks

Comment: I've made it work now. It should be noted also that when switching `ApplicationUser` from `IdentityUser` to `IdentityUser<string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>`, you will run into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671294/error-the-id-field-is-required-while-registering-new-user-in-database-with-a
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is it possible to normalize claims table? I mean divide it into 2 tables called `ClaimTypes` and `Claims` itself.