# Add a column to aspnetuserclaims table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, identity, claims-based-identity

I am quite new to identity so finding a bit hard. I have seen exactly what I am trying to achieve explained here ([Adding columns to AspNetUserClaims in ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42998020/adding-columns-to-aspnetuserclaims-in-asp-net-identity)) but I am looking for another solution where I do not need to edit my current implementation too much I have searched the internet and unable to find anything with a clear explanation or exactly what I need. From what I understand is that a claim has a type and value, what I need is the type, value and will need to add a page name to a claim. So my claims will be three values that are checked which will be ClaimType, ClaimValue and PageName. Just for clarification, I am using what I think is the default implementation of The Claims class.

This is My ApplicationDbContext.cs

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Application.Models.Claims> Claims { get; set; }

}
```

My ApplicationUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{              

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    //This method is responsible for getting the authenticated user identity
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);

        return userIdentity;
    }

}
```

As I said I am really new to this so I am really trying here, if I have forgotten anything that you may need to see to assist then please let me know. I am not sure if there is a way to inherit and add more columns from what I think the AspNetUserClaims table uses the IdentityUserClaim class. I have been trying to do this for days but unable to do so, would really appreciate any help if possible.

Comment: I had to store page name as well. I got around by saving the page name in the value itself separated by a  '|' symbol.

Comment: At the rate things are going I might have to do that because I cannot find any other way to do this :(, I managed to get another column in my table but after that, another column popped up called discriminator and then starts allowing duplicate claims for a user even though I had something before removing a claim if it already exists....I will try your solution in the meantime and will update you, but I hope someone will be able to provide a more ideal solution in the meantime if possible :) but will make do with this in the meantime